# Perl While loop is only checking first line of file

Tags: perl

I'm using the lines of one file (TARGET) to see if they are in another file (CHECK). It works if the TARGET file has a match in the first line, but not if it's anywhere else. It seems like the first while loop is only checking the first line from TARGET, instead of all the lines. How do I make it actually check all of the lines of the file?

```
while (my $line = <TARGET>) {
    chomp($line);
    while (my $check = <CHECK>) {
        if ($check =~ $line) {
            print "Found a match: $check";
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing lines in a file with perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260450/comparing-lines-in-a-file-with-perl)

Comment: Could you post some example input for `TARGET` and `CHECK`?

Comment: If you're making an entire perl script to compare lines within files, I'd recommend using the `comm` command instead.  It does exactly what you're looking for.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373810/unix-command-to-find-lines-common-in-two-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You scan the whole CHECK file handle for the first line of TARGET, then there are no more lines.  You need to rewind or reopen CHECK for each line of TARGET if you want to approach the task this way.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few things wrong with your code.

1. `$check =~ $line` is comparing the two by using `$line` as a regular expression.  You should use the string [comparison operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) to compare them: `$check eq $line`.
2. You `chomp($line)` but never `chomp($check)`.  This means that `$check` will always have it's trailing newline.
3. Reading lines from files moves the file pointer, which means after completing the inner `while` loop, `CHECK` will remain at end-of-file.  To prevent this, load the data into an array before looping.

Try the following and see if it works:

```
chomp( my @lines  = <TARGET> );
chomp( my @checks = <CHECK> );

for my $line (@lines) {
    for my $check (@checks) {
        if ( $line eq $check ) {
            print "Found match: $check" . $/;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That will still compare every line of the file corresponding to `CHECK` with only the *first* line of the file corresponding to `TARGET`. You would have to `seek` to the beginning of the second file on every iteration of the outer loop to actually compare every line in one file with every line in the other. Needless to say, that would be incredibly inefficient.

Comment: A better way (assuming the first file fits comfortably into memory) is to read the first file into a hash, then go through the second file line-by-line, checking if each line is in the hash.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. You're only reading from your CHECK file a single time, and then it's stuck at `eof`.
2. You're using regex comparison `=~` instead of a string comparison `eq`

I would recommend loading your CHECK file into a hash and then iterating on your other file:

```
my %check = map { $_ => 1 } <CHECK>;

while (<TARGET>) {
    if ( $check{$_} ) {
        print "Found a match: $_";
    }
}
```